# How to specify to only search within shared files using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a google drive where the majority of files and folders have been shared by all users.
But some files (and folders) might not be shared by **ALL** people.
Some files might even have not been shared at all.

I know you can view files not shared at all by entering `https://drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#query?view=2&visibility=4`  in the search bar (or choosing 'not shared' from the menu).
But I can't find a parameter for achieving that for a searchstring for DriveApp.searchFiles(str)

How can I specify to only search within files that have been shared?

```
   var searchString = "(trashed = false and hidden = false) and (fullText contains 'money')";
   var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchString);
```

or

```
  var searchString = "(trashed = false and hidden = false) and (fullText contains 'money')";
   var request = { 'q' :  searchString};
   var response = Drive.Files.list (request);
   var files = response.items;
```

While developing I have access to all files on my drive. But I would like to be able specify handling only those files that have been shared with **OTHERS** and not sharedWithMe nor owned by me.

So there are two situations
a) how can I specify to search in files shared by others at all ('sharedByMe')
b) how can I specify to search in files shared with a specific user ('sharedWithUser=abcd@gmail.com')

Comment: Hi @SoftwareTester, can you refrain from using the "GAS" abbreviation in further questions? The tags already clarify what language you're using and I'm not sure how many people really want to see it referred to as GAS. "google scripts" would be my vote if you want to keep some thing in the title. thx.

Comment: I've been asked 'what language' several times despite the code added. That's why I add it explicitely. The abbreviation I saw several times and is short. I'll think about it

Answer (score 0):

The search fields are documented [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) -

'shared with user x' is covered by readers and writers
'shared to no user' is not available within search, you would have to iterate through all files, testing for no readers and writers